# Eclipse key shortcut run no longer works on XML files

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

Since I updated to adt 21.0.1 I no longer can simply press 'CTRL+F11' to launch the current project when the current tab is an android layout XML file.

Using Eclipse 4.2 mobile edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in ADT 21.0.1. When reverting back to ADT 21.0.0 it all works fine again.

ps. where can I submit this bug?

Comment: I think this is the same issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42754

Answer (score 5):

Try Preferences->Run/Debug->Launching->Launch Operation = Always launch the previously launched operation

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the perspective from the top right.
Your default perspective might have changed to an android-specific one which does not support/recognize the XML/Java EE.

After the ADT installation, the current perspective selected might be JAVA.
Try changing it to JAVA EE if it is there.
I guess it should solve your problem.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Juno Mobile edition so JAVA EE is not there

Comment: what i meant was there must be more than 1 java perspectives available to you. Can you try selecting some other and see if the problem still exists?

Comment: Tried all the different JAVA * perspectives, to no avail

Comment: hmm...try updating eclipse then and install/reinstall the version(mobile edition)